# If HTTP Authentification exists, why custom form to authenticate?

Tags: php, http

If HTTP authentification exists, like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] === '...' &&
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] === '...') {
  // Process user login.
} else {
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Zone");
  header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
  die("Please enter username and password.");
}
```

Why google, facebook, everyone is using custom forms to perform authentifications? Am I missing something here?

Comment: HTTP authentication is implemented in the web server, not in your chosen programming language and database. You would still have to add that part, and if you do, why then rely on the server implementation?

Comment: Why do people use trains, when planes exist …? Because they are different things to begin with, have different purposes, operate on different levels.

Comment: Another detail: _"As the user ID and password are passed over the network as clear text (it is base64 encoded, but base64 is a reversible encoding), the basic authentication scheme **is not secure**."_ - taken from [MDN's HTTP Authentication manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication)

Comment: @El_Vanja: That's not a real problem, as the text you quote continues: _"HTTPS/TLS should be used with basic authentication. Without these additional security enhancements, basic authentication should not be used to protect sensitive or valuable information."_ The same is true for a normal web form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW` server variables are by default set when the server is configured with basic authentication and if the client provides credentials through an authentication header.

Sites generally don't use basic authentication because its user experience in browsers is ... horrific.

Using a login form and a POST handler that processes the form, sites can provide a user-friendly, customized login experience.